# Sistema de informacion distribuida c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual

Necesito ayuda con un proyecto, necesito que visual pase los datos al sql server pero no logro que lo realice, ya intente muchas maneras de youtube y algunos ejemplos de aquí pero nada.
Son solo 3 datos que necesito pasar:

- Clientes,
- Productos,
- Login

les agradezco de antemano su bondadosa ayuda

```
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP - U46PHOM\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Bonafesta;Integrated security = true");

private void btnsiguienteRenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand ("Insert into usuarios values(@Nombre,@Direccion@Telefono,@Correo)", conexion);
            conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvrenta.Rows)
                {
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Nombre"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Direccion"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Telefono"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Correo"].Value));
                    //agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaEntrega", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha_Entrega"].Value));
                    //agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoEvento", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Tipo_Evento"].Value));

                    agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Agregados");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar");
            }
                finally
            { 
            }
            {
                    conexion.Close();
            }

            Form Renta = new VistaRenta2();
            Renta.Show();
            Renta.Visible = true;
            Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Necesitamos que nos pases que hiciste de codigo, para verlo ordenado, deberias tener una conexion a la base de datos, luego con esa conexion se usan los comandos para enviar la info. y necesitamos saber de donde traes esa info.

Comment: agrega tu avance y de ahi partimos con la ayuda

Comment: pero cual seria el problema? el codigo parece correcto..

Comment: te lanza la excepcion?

Answer (score -3):

Ejemplo de como se hace un una llamada post en C#

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                  "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: y quien dijo que era un post lo que tiene que hacer OP?